# How can you print the scraped values in a paragraph format? Django

Tags: python, django

One quick question. I'm building a scraper that outputs emails. For now the emails get printed in a CSV file. But I want the emails to be outputted in a paragraph format on another URL. I've tried doing some things but it doesn't work out. Here is the code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render
from . scraper import EmailCrawler


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'leadfinderapp/scrape.html')

def scrape(request):
    url = request.GET.get('Email')
    crawl = EmailCrawler(url)
    crawl.crawl()

    return render(request, 'leadfinderapp/results.html')
```

Here is the html fie where I'm trying to output the emails (ignore the code) (results.html):

```
{% load static %}
<html>



    {% for email in scrape %}
    
    <p>{{ result }}</p>
    
    {% endfor %}
    
    </html>
```

email crawler (scraper.py):

```
import re
import requests
import requests.exceptions
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urljoin
from lxml import html
import sys
import csv


class EmailCrawler:

    processed_urls = set()
    unprocessed_urls = set()
    emails = set()

    def __init__(self, website: str):

        # processed_urls = set()
        # unprocessed_urls = set()
        # emails = set()
        emails = set()
        self.website = website
        self.email = emails
        self.unprocessed_urls.add(website)
        self.headers = {
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/78.0.3904.70 Chrome/78.0.3904.70 Safari/537.36',
        }
        self.base_url = urlsplit(self.website).netloc
        self.outputfile = self.base_url.replace('.','_')+'.csv'
        # we will use this list to skip urls that contain one of these extension. This will save us a lot of bandwidth and speedup the crawling process
        # for example: www.example.com/image.png --> this url is useless for us. we cannot possibly parse email from images and all other types of files.
        self.garbage_extensions = ['.aif','.cda','.mid','.midi','.mp3','.mpa','.ogg','.wav','.wma','.wpl','.7z','.arj','.deb','.pkg','.rar','.rpm','.tar.gz','.z','.zip','.bin','.dmg','.iso','.toast','.vcd','.csv','.dat','.db','.dbf','.log','.mdb','.sav','.sql','.tar','.apk','.bat','.bin','.cgi','.pl','.exe','.gadget','.jar','.py','.wsf','.fnt','.fon','.otf','.ttf','.ai','.bmp','.gif','.ico','.jpeg','.jpg','.png','.ps','.psd','.svg','.tif','.tiff','.asp','.cer','.cfm','.cgi','.pl','.part','.py','.rss','.key','.odp','.pps','.ppt','.pptx','.c','.class','.cpp','.cs','.h','.java','.sh','.swift','.vb','.ods','.xlr','.xls','.xlsx','.bak','.cab','.cfg','.cpl','.cur','.dll','.dmp','.drv','.icns','.ico','.ini','.lnk','.msi','.sys','.tmp','.3g2','.3gp','.avi','.flv','.h264','.m4v','.mkv','.mov','.mp4','.mpg','.mpeg','.rm','.swf','.vob','.wmv','.doc','.docx','.odt','.pdf','.rtf','.tex','.txt','.wks','.wps','.wpd']
        self.email_count = 0

    def crawl(self):
        """
        It will continue crawling untill the list unprocessed urls list is empty
        """

        url = self.unprocessed_urls.pop()
        print("CRAWL : {}".format(url))
        self.parse_url(url)


        if len(self.unprocessed_urls)!=0:
            self.crawl()
        else:
            print('End of crawling for {} '.format(self.website))
            print('Total urls visited {}'.format(len(self.processed_urls)))
            print('Total Emails found {}'.format(self.emails))


    def parse_url(self, current_url: str):
        """
        It will load and parse a given url. Loads it and finds all the url in this page.
        It also filters the urls and adds them to unprocessed url list.
        Finally it scrapes the emails if found on the page and the updates the email list

        INPUT:
            current_url: URL to parse
        RETURN:
            None
        """

        #we will retry to visit a url for 5 times in case it fails. after that we will skip it in case if it still fails to load
        response = requests.get(current_url, headers=self.headers)
        tree = html.fromstring(response.content)
        urls = tree.xpath('//a/@href')  # getting all urls in the page


        #Here we will make sure that we convert the sub domain to full urls
        # example --> /about.html--> https://www.website.com/about.html
        urls = [urljoin(self.website,url) for url in urls]
        # now lets make sure that we only include the urls that fall under our domain i.e filtering urls that point outside our main website.
        urls = [url for url in urls if self.base_url == urlsplit(url).netloc]


        #removing duplicates
        urls = list(set(urls))


        #filtering  urls that point to files such as images, videos and other as listed on garbage_extensions
        #Here will loop through all the urls and skip them if they contain one of the extension
        parsed_url = []
        for url in urls:
            skip = False
            for extension in self.garbage_extensions:
                if not url.endswith(extension) and  not url.endswith(extension+'/'):
                    pass
                else:
                    skip = True
                    break
            if not skip:
                parsed_url.append(url)

        # finally filtering urls that are already in queue or already visited
        for url in parsed_url:
            if url not in self.processed_urls and url not in self.unprocessed_urls:
                self.unprocessed_urls.add(url)


        #parsing email
        self.parse_emails(response.text)
        # adding the current url to processed list
        self.processed_urls.add(current_url)



    def parse_emails(self, text: str):
        """
        It scans the given texts to find email address and then writes them to csv
        Input:
            text: text to parse emails from
        Returns:
            bool: True or false (True if email was found on page)
        """
        # parsing emails and then saving to csv
        emails = set(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+', text, re.I))
        #TODO: sometime "gFJS3amhZEg_z39D5EErVg@2x.png" gets accepted as email with the above regex. so for now i will check if email ends with jpeg,png and jpg

        for email in emails:
            skip_email = False
            for checker in ['jpg','jpeg','png']:
                if email.endswith(checker):
                    skip_email = True
                    break

            if not skip_email:
                if email not in self.emails:
                    print(email)


                    self.email_count +=1
                    self.emails.add(email)

        if len(emails)!=0:
            return True
        else:
            return False


#try:
#    website = sys.argv[1]
#except:
#   website = input("Please enter a website to crawl for emails:")
#crawl = EmailCrawler(website)
#crawl.crawl()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the results as context in the render method!

What does your crawl() method return? If it returns a list of emails you should do something like:

```
   # ...
   email_list = crawl.crawl()
   return render(request, 'leadfinderapp/results.html', {"email_list": email_list})
```

Then in the template you can loop over them:

```
{% for email in email_list %}
<p> {{ email }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**

The crawl method does not return anything. Therefore my suggestion above (which assumes a list is returned) will not work...

I see that that method is called recursively, so, what I suggest is you update a class-level variable at each iteration:

1. define email_list in your init (or you can use you current email set perhaps?!)
2. append the scraped emails to that variable from within the crawl method at each iteration
3. then in your view:

   ```
   def scrape(request):
       url = request.GET.get('Email')
       crawl = EmailCrawler(url)
       crawl.crawl()
       email_list = crawl.email_list # or whatever class-level variable you use
       return render(request, 'leadfinderapp/results.html', {"email_list": email_list)
   ```

Comment: it returns a white screen in that case. Probably it is because in the scrapper code I need to print the values?

Comment: No, you don't need to print anything. Passing a context dictionary via the view means that that context becomes available in the template to be displayed. Please paste the code of your `EmailCrawler.crawl()` method